# JQgrid not showing data while rows are generating

Tags: json, knockout.js, jqgrid, jsonreader

Jqgrid is not showing JSON data, however rows are generating

Server side code:

```
public JsonResult Denominations()
{
.
.
int counter = 0;
var jsonData = new
{
total = result.UserObject.Count,
page = 1,
rows = (
      from p in result.UserObject
      select new
      {
            id = ++counter,
            cell = new string [] { 
                   p.CurrencyID.ToString(), 
                   p.DenominationID.ToString(), 
                   p.DenominationName.ToString(), 
                   p.DenominatorCount.ToString(), 
                   p.Multiplier.ToString(), 
                   p.TenderID.ToString()
                     }
                 }).ToArray()

            };
            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Data from server side is like this:**
{"total":1,"page":1,"rows":[{"id":1,"cell":["1","1","Penny","0","0.0100","1"]}]}

JavaScript code:

```
$("#denominators").jqGrid({
        url: '/Denominations?tenderid=1&currencyid=1',
        contentType: "application/json",
        datatype: "json",
        jsonReader: {
            root: 'rows',
            page: 'page',
            total: 'total',
            repeatitems: false,
            cell: 'cell',
            id: 'id',
            userdata:'userdata'
        },
        mtype: "GET",
        colNames: ["CurrencyID", "DenominationID", "TenderID", "Multiplier", "DenominationName", "DenominatorCount"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "currencyid", width: 80, align: "center" },
            { name: "denominationid", width: 90, align: "center" },
            { name: "tenderid", width: 250 },
            { name: "multiplier", width: 250 },
            { name: "denominationname", width: 95 },
            { name: "denominatorcount", width: 95 },
        ],
        height: 'auto',
        loadonce: true,
        sortname: "DenominationID",
        sortorder: "desc",
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        autoencode: true
    });
```

View:

```
<table id="denominators" ></table>
```

View creates the grid with column header however rows are generated but rows did not any data int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use wrong `jsonReader`. To be exactly the property `repeatitems: false` is false. It means that the format of every item in `rows` array is

```
{
    "currencyid": "1",
    "denominationid": "1",
    "tenderid": 1,
    "denominationname": "Penny",
    "denominatorcount": "0",
    "multiplier": "0.0100"
}
```

You use

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "cell": [
        "1",
        "1",
        "Penny",
        "0",
        "0.0100",
        "1"
    ]
}
```

instead. So you should remove `jsonReader` because the format of input data corresponds the default `jsonReader`, but you need still reorder the columns of the grid or change the order of items which you place in `cell` array so that it corresponds the order of columns in `colModel`.

Additional remarks: you use wrong value for `total`. It should be the number of *pages*. By the way you use `loadonce: true`. In the case you can remove `"total":1,"page":1` part from the response and just return array of *named* items. You should just choose the names of columns the same as the names of properties if the items.